# React Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having some problems with authentication in my React template.
When I'm logged in it work's fine, but when I log out I'm receiving message like.

> Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): Element type is invalid:
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `Route`.

Here is how my code looks like.

```
const Dashboard = ({ match, isAuthenticated }) => (
    <Col span={24}>
        <Menu
            mode="horizontal"
        >
            <Menu.Item key="News">
                <Link to="./News"><i className="icon icon-alert gx-text-white" /> News</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="Servers">
                <Link to="./Servers"><i className="icon icon-widgets gx-text-white" />Servers</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="Billing">
                <Link to="./Billing"><i className="icon icon-pricing-table gx-text-white" />Billing</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="Support">
                <Link to="./Support"><i className="icon icon-chat-bubble gx-text-white" />Support</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="Logs">
                <Link to="./Logs"><i className="icon icon-plain-list-divider gx-text-white" />Activity Logs</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
        <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from={`${match.url}/`} to={`${match.url}/News`} />

            <Route path={`${match.url}/servers`}
                component={isAuthenticated ? asyncComponent(() => import('./Servers')) :
                    <Redirect to="/home" />} />
        </Switch >
    </Col>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.token !== null
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Dashboard);
```

Comment: Try this `component={ () => isAuthenticated ? asyncComponent(() => import('./Servers')) :
                    <Redirect to="/home" />}`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Route path={`${match.url}/servers`}
  component={isAuthenticated
    ? asyncComponent(() => import('./Servers'))
    : <Redirect to="/home" />} />
```

this is probably not valid, your `<Redirect to="/home" />` will be evaluated right away in `render` and its result will be provided to `component`, not actually the Redirect component.

One thing you could try is changing it to `() => <Redirect to="/home" />`

this way you are basically providing an "inline SFC" to `component` which is only evaluated when it is actually being rendered by `Route` when `isAuthenticated` is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
This is the code that works.

```
<Route path={`${match.url}/news`}
                component={isAuthenticated
                    ? asyncComponent(() => import('./News'))
                    : () => <Redirect to="/home" />} />
```